# Parse JSON using python to fetch value based on condition

Tags: python, json

I am new to python and trying to parse the json file and fetch the required field based on condition.

eg., if status = true, then
         print name

Json file:

```
[
  {
    "id": "12345",
    "name": "London",
    "active": true,
    "status": "true",
    "version": "1.0",
    "tags": [
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "12457",
    "name": "Newyork",
    "active": true,
    "status": "false",
    "version": "1.1",
    "tags": [
    ]
  },
]
```

expected output:

name : London

Please help me on this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import json
>>> obj = json.loads('[ { "id": "12345", "name": "London", "active": true, "status": "true", "version": "1.0", "tags": [ ] }, { "id": "12457", "name": "Newyork", "active": true, "status": "false", "version": "1.1", "tags": [ ] } ]')
>>> print "Names:", ",".join(x["name"] for x in obj if x["status"] == "true")
Names: London
```

---

Your JSON is invalid. Remove the comma as below:

```
[
  {
    "id": "12345",
    "name": "London",
    "active": true,
    "status": "true",
    "version": "1.0",
    "tags": [
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "12457",
    "name": "Newyork",
    "active": true,
    "status": "false",
    "version": "1.1",
    "tags": [
    ]
  },
   ^__________Remove this comma!
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, below is the error which i have got

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample2.py", line 2, in <module>
    obj = json.loads("/home/dir/testing/file")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 338, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Thats because of a trailing comma in your original JSON. I fixed that in my code above.

Comment: Hi Thrustmaster, I have used the above code but the same error.. I am passing json content through file(json.loads("/home/dir/testing/file") ) Am i missing anything? please help me

Comment: Thank you thrustmaster for helping me on this. When i paste the code and execute. it is working as expected. but when i pass json content as file, it is throwing those errors. I have checked the file content, there is no comma, in the end of file. Could you please share how to pass json content through file instead having json content directly in the code.

Answer (score -1):

You can get all info about json parsing here.

http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html