# Getting the specified data from the json format using python?

Tags: python, json

I am having a json data like this 
and I want the specific data from this json format based on the condition given below

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "W012A3CDE",
            "team_id": "T012AB3C4",
            "name": "spengler",
            "deleted": false,
            "color": "9f69e7",
            "real_name": "spengler",
            "tz": "America/Los_Angeles",
            "tz_label": "Pacific Daylight Time",
            "tz_offset": -25200,
            "profile": {
                "avatar_hash": "ge3b51ca72de",
                "status_text": "Print is dead",
                "status_emoji": ":books:",

            }

        },
        {
            "id": "W07QCRPA4",
            "team_id": "T0G9PQBBK",
            "name": "glinda",
            "deleted": false,
            "color": "9f69e7",
            "real_name": "Glinda Southgood",
            "tz": "America/Los_Angeles",
            "tz_label": "Pacific Daylight Time",
            "tz_offset": -25200,
            "profile": {
                "phone": "",
                "skype": "",
                "real_name": "Glinda Southgood",
                "real_name_normalized": "Glinda Southgood",
                "display_name": "Glinda the Fairly Good",
                "display_name_normalized": "Glinda the Fairly Good",
                "email": "glenda@south.oz.coven"
            },

        }
    ],
    "cache_ts": 1498777272,
    "response_metadata": {
        "next_cursor": "dXNlcjpVMEc5V0ZYTlo="
    }
}
```

now I want to get only name and id from the members where deleted:false from this json format using python Can anyone help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON using python to fetch value based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621357/parse-json-using-python-to-fetch-value-based-on-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple list comprehension should be enough assuming you've managed to load the json into a dict.

```
response = json.loads(<your_json_string_here>)
undeleted_members = [dict(id=member['id'], name=member['name']) for member in response['members'] if not member['deleted']]
print(undeleted_members)
```

Returns a list of dicts with just the name & ID like:

```
{'id': 'W07QCRPA4', 'name': 'glinda'}
```

Or if you want separate lists for IDs & names:

```
all_ids = [member['id'] for member in response['members'] if not member['deleted']]
all_names = [member['name'] for member in response['members'] if not member['deleted']]
```

Comment: with your code I am getting error like this 
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response
can you help me @ rdas

Comment: You have a response object. You need to get the response data (probably from `response.text`) before passing it to `json.loads()`

Comment: How to get the response.text can you tell me

Comment: Yes got it but I want to get it as an list of arrays is it possible

Comment: 2 separate lists for id & name or a list of tuples like [(id, name), (id, name), ...`

Comment: 2 seperate lists for id and name [allids],[allnames]

Comment: Edited to include that as well